# asmx on an existing site gives me namespace not found

Tags: c#, web-config, asmx, iis-8

Been looking around but cannot find an answer. I wrote an asmx on VS2012 locally works good. Now deploying to the remote target site it is becoming an issue. On that site there are other asmx services and in their global web.config they have this section

```
...
<system.webServer>
...
   <handlers>
   ...
     <add name="ScriptHandlerFactory" verb="*" path="*.asmx"     preCondition="integratedMode"    type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=123456789" />
   ...  
   </handlers>
...
</system.webServer>
```

I placed my asmx on a subfolder defining an Application on IIS8 and I'm trying to overwrite that global setting with my local web.config, tried different permutations on the local `web.config` with location to avoid inheritance but so far it always gives me the lovely

> Server error in '/my_svc' Application
>       CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ForeignNS' could not be found

Is it possible to override it by only changing my local `web.config`? If so how? If at all possible? Target site admin will not allow to change global `web.config` unless it is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Did you ensure that an assembly that contains `ForeignNS` type or namespace exists on the server?

Comment: That is the for several asmx that were there before mine,

Comment: Well after many trial and error it seemed like the solution was to copy a bunch of DLLs from the existing asmx 's(all with namespace ForeignNS) to my local bin folder and setting a navigation.config.  But I wonder if there is a cleaner way, the main web.config is not blocking overrride